# Powershell - now to extract name of variable passed to script

Tags: python, parameters, powershell-2.0

I am writing powershell script to interface with an external software program our company is using

The script needs to take in value of the input parameter and do something.

But the problem is, this external software pushes **many** input parameters with the names

- sender-email
- sender-ip
- sender-port
- endpoint-user-name
- endpoint-machine-name

I only need the value for **sender-ip**. But my problem is

1. I don't know in which order the external program is inputting the parameters to the script
2. Powershell naming convention does not allow for a hyphen, so it's not like I can just start using **sender-ip** without getting an error *The term 'sender-ip' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.*

Here is my script so far

```
param([string]$Sender_IP=$(**sender-ip**))
$eventList = @()
Get-EventLog "Security" -computername $Sender_IP `
        | Where -FilterScript {$_.EventID -eq 4624 -and $_.ReplacementStrings[4].Length -gt 10 -and $_.ReplacementStrings[5] -notlike "*$"} `
        | Select-Object -First 2 `
        | foreach-Object {
            $row = "" | Select UserName, LoginTime
            $row.UserName = $_.ReplacementStrings[5]
            $row.LoginTime = $_.TimeGenerated
            $eventList += $row
            }
$UserId = $eventList[0].UserName

$UserID
```

See, when I manually invoke `foo.psl *ip_address*,` everything works well. But if I call the program without parameter, I get error.

How to write code such as

```
if name of input variable is **sender-ip** 
   do something
else if name of input variable is something different 
   ignore
```

**I am not evaluating value of the input parameter**, I want to capture the input parameter that is named sender-ip, and from there I will run the script and evaluate.

I hope I explained my question well.

In the past, people interfaced with this third party program using Python script, where you can simply write the following

```
attributeMap = parseInput(args) 
dateSent = attributeMap["sender-ip"]
```

I strongly prefer to use powershell.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If I were you I would probably start with looking at actual input to your script when your program runs...

If it will however just do:

```
.\yourscript.ps1 -foo-bar something -something-else value -sender-ip yourdata
```

You can get the value of sender-ip very easily:

```
param (
    ${sender-ip}
)
"Sender IP = ${sender-ip}"
```

If that's not the case you will probably have to paste here what you get when you do simple `$args` in your script. Without seeing what is there it may be hard to suggest something similar to thing that python does...

**EDIT**

In case you receive data as name=value pairs, try this:

```
function foo {
    $hash = ConvertFrom-StringData -StringData ($Args -Join "`n")
    $hash.'sender-ip'
}
foo test-first=alfa sender-ip=beta
```

In my test I got expected (beta) result...

Comment: Hello Bartek I just found that the input of my script will be strings, i.e. "sender-ip=10.2.4.1" "sender-email=joe@gmail.com" "sender-port=8014", etc. This makes life easier because I can simply split the arguments into an array, and then split each argument based on '=' and from there, store into a hash.

Comment: I added some code that should simplify it for you. It uses `ConvertFrom-StringData` cmdlet that was designed to convert `name=value` pairs into hashtable with `name` key pointing to `value` value.